# Getting GIT build hash outside the current directory

Tags: git, cmake

I'm using CMake to do an out-of-core/out-of-source build of my project, and want to include the result of a "git describe --tags --dirty" as a version number in the project (just for reference on bugs).  However, any attempt to try and tell git where the code repo is results in an error like "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git".

Is there a way to specify where git should look for the repo, other than the current working directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can use the `WORKING_DIRECTORY`-argument to `execute_process()` from cmake. This is what I do:

```
execute_process(COMMAND "${GIT_EXECUTABLE}" describe --tags --dirty
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"
    RESULT_VARIABLE res
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE out
    ERROR_QUIET
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
```

And then I have the version in `${out}`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `git` with `--git-dir`-argument.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `--git-dir` on the command line, or set `GIT_DIR` in the environment, or write the path into a file named `.git`: `echo gitdir: /path/to/.git > .git` or make a soft link to the repo: `ln -s /path/to/.git`.

(The last two options are probably the least desirable, and merely mentioned here for completeness.)

Answer (score 1):

> You can specify --git-dir on the command line

Beware: this would not work fully before Git 2.21 (Feb. 2019):
"`git --work-tree=$there --git-dir=$here describe --dirty`" did not work correctly as it did not pay attention to the location of the worktree specified by the user by mistake, which has been corrected.

See [commit c801170](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c801170b0cbc3fdd44331a53c2b7649687625680), [commit 2ed5c8e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ed5c8e174dae73459df11386dc83e8ef4154e3f) (03 Feb 2019) by [Sebastian Staudt (`koraktor`)](https://github.com/koraktor).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a1e1900](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1e19004e11dcbc0ceebd92c425ceb1770e52d0b), 07 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### `describe`: setup working tree for `--dirty`
>
> We don't use `NEED_WORK_TREE` when running the `git-describe` builtin,
>   since you should be able to describe a commit even in a bare repository.
>   However, the `--dirty` flag does need a working tree. Since we don't call
>   `setup_work_tree()`, it uses whatever directory we happen to be in. That's
>   unlikely to match our index, meaning we'd say "dirty" even when the real
>   working tree is clean.
>
> We can fix that by calling `setup_work_tree()` once we know that the user
>   has asked for `--dirty`.
>
> The `--broken` option also needs a working tree. But because its implementation calls `git-diff-index` we don‘t have to setup the working tree in the `git-describe` process.