# Applying the existing tag on a new commit in Git

Tags: git, git-tag

I have a tag named tag_0.0.1 which is being pushed in the same to Git Repository. I run the build several times a day. Instead of creating new tags every time, I want to rewrite the same tag. New changes should be applied on the existing tag and it can be pushed to the repo. I know we can delete the tag on the repo and create the same in local and push it. Is there any way to apply new commits on the existing tags ?

This is what i tried:

git tag

### tag_0.0.1

After code changes -- deleting

git tag -d tag_0.0.1

### git push --delete origin tag_0.0.1

Recreating the same and push

git tag tag_0.0.1

git push --tags

I have a feeling about it doesn't make a sense. Is there any better ways ? I also want to know how to push the specific commit instead of pushing all of them.

Comment: Git tag is a stamp, it should be used as such. If you don't want to create new tags endlessly, don't create tags at all. Only tag a release or an important milestone.

Comment: You are right. But I wanted to do this as part of build automation. Every build changes should be tagged. so that we can get the specific commit at anytime. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You don't need to git tag *every single build* just to get a specific commit. All you need to do is save the commit hash (or first few letters of it) and you can check it out at any time...

Comment: Remember if you checkout a tag, you are in the detached head mode and commits created in this mode are harder to find after you checkout a branch again

Answer (score 2):

> Every build changes should be tagged. so that we can get the specific commit at anytime.

Your build process should rather incorporate the last tag and the current SHA1, using [`git describe`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe).

You can see an example in "[Automatic versioning in Xcode with git-describe](http://zargony.com/2014/08/10/automatic-versioning-in-xcode-with-git-describe)" (or even [`git describe --dirty`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17537385/6309)), using

```
VERSION=`git describe --dirty |sed -e "s/^[^0-9]*//"`
```

Other examples:

- "[Embed git commit hash in a .Net dll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15141338/6309)"
- "[Maven plugin which includes build-time git repository information into an POJO / `*.properties`](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin)"

That way:

- the binary you are building includes the information allowing you to know what exact version of the code was used to make said build.
- you limit the tags to the actual versions that count (like a stable version used to make an official release)

Comment: Seems git describe only shows annotated tags. But I create lightweight tags only. Anyway I will give a try. Thanks bunch.